# Postgres - select logic

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data in my table A.

```
team | name | status | start_date | end_date
----------------------------------------------
A      Ann    Active  2016-01-01   2016-06-01
A      Linh   Active  2016-01-01   2016-06-01
A      John   Hold    2016-01-01   2016-06-01
A      Soph   Closed  2016-01-01   2016-06-01
```

I can do `select from table A where status='Active'` to get the active members.

Now, the requirement has changed to that if there **at least one** "Active" status member, I should look for both "Active" and "Hold" status members in the query.

If there is not "Active" status member, then I should NOT look for "Hold" status members.

How should I write in one SQL?

Comment: Does "at least one "Active" status member..." mean "if there's *at least one record* in the *entire table* with `Active` status..." (in the sample it's true - we have the very1st record with `Active` status)

Comment: ...Or "at least one "Active" status member..." means if a *person* has a record  with `Active` status you should provide records of *this person* with *both* `Active` and `Hold` statuses? (`John` should be excluded, he doesn't have any records with `Active` status)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `f there is not "Active" status member, then I should NOT include other status members` leads me to different interpretation. Please author post expected result and add some sample data?..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your requirement, this query is working :

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA
 WHERE status IN ('Active', 'Hold')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT true FROM tableA WHERE status = 'Active');
```

Hope this help.